# Layering two Vaadin canvases together with CSS

Tags: java, css, canvas, vaadin

I have two canvases - the bottom canvas for loading of image, and the top canvas for drawing of bounding boxes etc (meaning the top canvas has all the mouse listeners etc). In my main layout, I create these two canvases (bottom canvas first). This works, and I can see two canvases being loaded - however, I need them to be layered on top of each other instead of separated. When I edit the positioning in my CSS file, I can actually see the two canvases being properly layered, however there is a huge white space left below (the size of a canvas), and my buttons which are supposed to be positioned below the canvas are all now positioned to the top left of the page.

This is my MainLayout.java:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2000-2017 Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.HtmlImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.receivers.MultiFileMemoryBuffer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.service.UserService;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.*;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The main layout contains the header with the navigation buttons, and the
 * child views below that.
 */

@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
@Route("")
@Theme(Lumo.class)
public class MainLayout extends Div {

    private CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx;
    private Canvas imgCanvas;
    private Canvas canvas;
    ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray = Canvas.getMousePosArray();
    ArrayList<BoundingBox> bb = Canvas.getArrayBoxes();
    public static int count = 0;

    public MainLayout() {

        Div divlayout = new Div();

        H2 title = new H2("Annotation UI");
        title.addClassName("main-layout__title");

        imgCanvas = new Canvas(Canvas.imgOne, 0, 0, 1580, 700);
        canvas = new Canvas(1580, 700);

        imgCanvas.addClassName("imgCanvas");
        canvas.addClassName("canvas");

        ctx = canvas.getContext();
        add(imgCanvas);
        add(canvas);

        Div buttons = new Div();

//        MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer = new MultiFileMemoryBuffer();
//        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
//        upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif");
//
//        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
//            Component component = createComponent(event.getMIMEType(),
//                    event.getFileName(),
//                    buffer.getInputStream(event.getFileName()));
//            showOutput(event.getFileName(), component, output);
//        });

        Button saveButton = new Button("Save Annotations");
        saveButton.addClickListener( e-> {
            UserService service = new UserService();
            try {
                service.run();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        });
        buttons.add(saveButton);
        saveButton.addClassName("saveButton");

        Button previousButton = new Button("Previous Picture");
        previousButton.addClickListener(event -> { canvas.previousPicture();});
        buttons.add(previousButton);
        previousButton.addClassName("previousButton");

        Button nextButton = new Button("Next Picture");
        nextButton.addClickListener(event -> { canvas.nextPicture();});
        buttons.add(nextButton);
        nextButton.addClassName("nextButton");

        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete Selected");
        deleteButton.addClickListener(event -> { canvas.deleteSelected();});
        buttons.add(deleteButton);
        deleteButton.addClassName("deleteButton");

        Button undoButton = new Button("Undo Canvas");
        undoButton.addClickListener(event -> { canvas.undoLast();});
        buttons.add(undoButton);
        undoButton.addClassName("undoButton");

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear Canvas");
        clearButton.addClickListener(event -> { ctx.clearCanvas(Canvas.imgOne, 0,0,1580,700);});
        buttons.add(clearButton);
        clearButton.addClassName("clearButton");

        add(buttons);

        Label label = new Label();
        canvas.addComponent(label);
        add(label);

        TextField boxname = new TextField();
        boxname.setPlaceholder("Box Name");
        boxname.addClassName("boxname");

        TextField boxcategory = new TextField();
        boxcategory.setPlaceholder("Box Category");
        boxcategory.addClassName("boxcategory");
        add(boxname, boxcategory);

        ComboBox<String> coloursMenu = new ComboBox<>();
        coloursMenu.setPlaceholder("Box Colour");
        coloursMenu.setItems("Aqua", "Blue", "Black",
                "Green", "Magenta", "Orange", "Pink", "Red", "Turquoise", "Yellow");
        coloursMenu.addClassName("boxcolour");
        add(coloursMenu);

        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setPicID(ImageCanvas.getImgOne());
            bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setName(boxname.getValue());
            bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setBoxcategory(boxcategory.getValue());
            bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setBoxcolour(coloursMenu.getValue());
            BoundingBox box = bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1);
            Canvas.boxStyle(box);
            boxname.clear();
            boxcategory.clear();
            coloursMenu.clear();
            System.out.println(bb.toString());

            System.out.println("Box Count: " + Canvas.boxCount);

        });

        add(submitButton);
        submitButton.addClassName("submitButton");

        canvas.addMouseMoveListener(() -> label.setText("Coordinates: " + mousePosArray.get(0)));
        label.addClassName("coordinates");
        }
    }
```

Canvas.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasSize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasStyle;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.ElementFactory;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend.MainLayout;
import elemental.html.ImageElement;
import elemental.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.impl.Action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Canvas component that you can draw shapes and images on. It's a Java wrapper
 * for the
 * <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API">HTML5
 * canvas</a>.
 * <p>
 * Use {@link #getContext()} to get API for rendering shapes and images on the
 * canvas.
 * <p>
 */
@Tag("canvas")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends Component implements HasStyle, HasSize {

    private static CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
    private Element element;
    private boolean mouseSelect = false;
    private boolean mouseIsDown = false;
    private double endX;
    private double endY;

    public Image image;
    public static int boxCount = 0;
    public static boolean undoCalled = false;
    public static int selectedBox = 0;
    public static boolean boxSelected = false;
    public static int imageArrayCount = 0;
    public static boolean imageLoaded = false;

    public static String imgOne = "https://wanderersandwarriors.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Chinatown-Singapore-%e2%80%93-A-Tourist-Guide-3-1440x960.jpg";
    public static String imgTwo = "https://www.weekendnotes.com/im/006/02/orchard-road1.jpg";
    public static String imgThree = "http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/www-singapore-com/homepage/attractions/sentosa-island/pagePropertiesImage/sentosa-attractions.jpg.jpg";

    public static ArrayList <BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();
    public static ArrayList <MousePosition> mousePosArray = new ArrayList<MousePosition>();
    public static ArrayList <SelectBox> selectBoxes = new ArrayList<SelectBox>();
    private List<Runnable> mouseMoveListeners = new ArrayList<>(0);
    public static ArrayList<String> imageArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String getImgOne() {
        return imgOne;
    }

    public void setImgOne(String imgOne) {
        this.imgOne = imgOne;
    }

    public static String getImgTwo() {
        return imgTwo;
    }

    public void setImgTwo(String imgTwo) {
        this.imgTwo = imgTwo;
    }

    public static String getImgThree() {
        return imgThree;
    }

    public void setImgThree(String imgThree) {
        this.imgThree = imgThree;
    }

    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> getArrayBoxes() {
        return arrayBoxes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<MousePosition> getMousePosArray() {
        return mousePosArray;
    }

    public static void setMousePosArray(ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray) {
        Canvas.mousePosArray = mousePosArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new canvas component with the given size.
     * <p>
     * Use the API provided by {@link #getContext()} to render graphics on the
     * canvas.
     * <p>
     * The width and height parameters will be used for the canvas' coordinate
     * system. They will determine the size of the component in pixels, unless
     * you explicitly set the component's size with {@link #setBoxwidth(String)} or
     * {@link #setBoxheight(String)}.
     *
//     * @param width
//     *            the width of the canvas
//     * @param height
//     *            the height of the canvas
//     */

    public Registration addMouseMoveListener(Runnable listener) {
        mouseMoveListeners.add(listener);
        return () -> mouseMoveListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public Canvas(String src, double x, double y, int width, int height){
        context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(this);

        element = getElement();
        element.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        getElement().setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
        getElement().setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));

        context.drawImage(imgOne, 0, 0);
    }

    public Canvas(int width, int height) {

        imageArray.add(imgOne);
        imageArray.add(imgTwo);
        imageArray.add(imgThree);

        context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(this);

//        context.drawImage(imageArray.get(0), 0, 0);
        imageArrayCount = 0;

        element = getElement();
        element.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        getElement().setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
        getElement().setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve starting x and y position

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox("","","", "", xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

            mouseIsDown=true;

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

        element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draws box + selection of boxes

            Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

            JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

            endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
            endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

            double xcoordi = 0;
            double ycoordi = 0;
            double boxWidth = 0;
            double boxHeight = 0;

            for (int i = boxCount; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setEndX(endX);
                arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setEndY(endY);
                if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi() != arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndY()) {  // If startY and endY is the same, means user selected a box and not drew a box
                    arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setBoxwidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).xcoordi);
                    arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setBoxheight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).ycoordi);
                    xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getXcoordi();
                    ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getYcoordi();
                    boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getBoxwidth();
                    boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getBoxheight();
                    boxCount++;

                    mouseIsDown = false;

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.setStrokeStyle("green");
                    context.setLineWidth(2);
                    context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                    context.stroke();
//                    context.fill();

                } else {
                    if (arrayBoxes.size() > 0) {
                        arrayBoxes.remove(arrayBoxes.size() - 1);
                        mouseSelect = true;

                        SelectBox select = new SelectBox(endX, endY);
                        selectBoxes.add(0, select);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mouseSelect == true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                    if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getXcoordi() < selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectX() &&  selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectX() < arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndX())
                        if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndY() > selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectY() && selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectY() > arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi()) {
                            System.out.println("Selected Box Name: " + arrayBoxes.get(i).boxname);
                            selectedBox = i;
                            boxSelected = true;

                            mouseSelect = false;
                     }
                     else {
                     mouseSelect = false;
                     }
                }
                context.beginPath();
                context.setStrokeStyle("yellow");
                context.setLineWidth(3);
                context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).getXcoordi() - 2, arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).getYcoordi() - 2, arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).boxWidth + 4, arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).boxHeight + 4);
                context.stroke();
//                context.fill();

            }


            System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

        element.addEventListener("mousemove", event -> {  // Retrieve mouse position when moving

                JsonObject mousePos = event.getEventData();

                double mouseX = mousePos.getNumber("event.x");
                double mouseY = mousePos.getNumber("event.y");

                MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
                mousePosArray.add(0, currentPos);
                setMousePosArray(mousePosArray);
            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

     }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

    }

    public static void boxStyle(BoundingBox box) {  // Change box colour and add label (name, category) to top left corner
        context.setFillStyle(box.getBoxcolour());
        context.setFont("bold 10pt Arial");
        context.fillText(box.getBoxName(), box.getXcoordi() + 5, box.getYcoordi() - 5);
        context.setFillStyle(box.getBoxcolour());
        context.fillText(box.getBoxcategory(), box.getXcoordi() + 5, box.getYcoordi() + 15);

        context.beginPath();
        context.setStrokeStyle(box.getBoxcolour());
        context.setLineWidth(2);
        context.strokeRect(box.getXcoordi(), box.getYcoordi(), box.getBoxwidth(), box.getBoxheight());
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }

    public static void deleteSelected() {  // Deletes the current box that has been selected
        arrayBoxes.remove(selectedBox);
        boxCount--;

        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1600, 800);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("green");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
            context.fill();
            BoundingBox box = arrayBoxes.get(i);
            Canvas.boxStyle(box);
        }

        System.out.println(arrayBoxes);


    }

    public void undoLast() {  // Removes the last drawn box from the canvas and the arrayBoxes array

        undoCalled = true;

        if (arrayBoxes.size() > 0) {
            arrayBoxes.remove(arrayBoxes.size() - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.size());

        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1580, 700);
        context.drawImage(imageArray.get(0), 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("green");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
//            context.fill();
//            BoundingBox box = getArrayBoxes().get(boxCount);
            BoundingBox box = arrayBoxes.get(i);
            Canvas.boxStyle(box);
        }

        boxCount--;
        System.out.println("Box Count: " + boxCount);
    }

    public void previousPicture(){
        context.clearCanvas(imageArray.get(0),0,0,1600,800);
    }

    public void nextPicture(){
        context.clearCanvas(imageArray.get(0), 0,0,1580,700);
    }

    public void setImage(String src){
        image = new Image();
        image.setSrc(src);
    }

    public void paintImage(){
        context.drawImage(imageArray.get(0), 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the context for rendering shapes and images in the canvas.
     * <p>
     * It is a Java wrapper for the <a href=
     * "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D">same
     * client-side API</a>.
     *
     * @return the 2D rendering context of this canvas
     */
    public CanvasRenderingContext2D getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
//    @Override
//    public void setBoxwidth(String width) {
//        HasSize.super.setBoxwidth(width);
//    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
//    @Override
//    public void setBoxheight(String height) {
//        HasSize.super.setBoxheight(height);
//    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setSizeFull() {
        HasSize.super.setSizeFull();
    }

    public void addComponent(Label label) {
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2000-2017 Vaadin Ltd.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  ~ use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  ~ the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  ~ the License.
  -->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-lumo-styles/typography.html">

<dom-module id="view-styles">
    <template>
        <style>
            /* Stretch to fill the entire browser viewport while keeping the content constrained to
            parent element max-width */

            .view-toolbar {
                display: flex;
                background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
                margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);
                padding: 8px calc(50vw - 50% + 16px);
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                flex: none;
            }

            .view-toolbar__search-field {
                flex: auto;
                min-width: 0;
                margin-right: 16px;
            }
            .view-container {
                flex: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<custom-style>
    <style include="view-styles">
        html {
            height: auto;
            --main-layout-header-height: 64px;
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }

        body {
            /* Avoid horizontal scrollbars, mainly on IE11 */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            background-color: var(--lumo-contrast-5pct);
        }

        .main-layout {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .main-layout__title {
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 0;
            /* Allow the nav-items to take all the space so they are centered */
            width: 0;
            line-height: 1;
            letter-spacing: -0.02em;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .main-layout > * {
            flex: auto;
        }

        .main-layout__header {
            display: flex;
            flex: none;
            align-items: center;
            height: var(--main-layout-header-height);

            /* Stretch to fill the entire browser viewport, while keeping the content constrained to
               parent element max-width */
            margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);
            padding: 0 calc(50vw - 50% + 16px);

            background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 var(--lumo-contrast-5pct);
        }

        .main-layout__nav {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .main-layout__nav-item {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s color, 0.3s transform;
            will-change: transform;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            font-size: var(--lumo-font-size-s);
            color: var(--lumo-secondary-text-color);
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 1.3;
        }

        .main-layout__nav-item:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .main-layout__nav-item:not([highlight]):hover {
            color: inherit;
        }

        .main-layout__nav-item[highlight] {
            color: var(--lumo-primary-text-color);
            cursor: default;
        }

        .main-layout__nav-item iron-icon {
            /* Vaadin icons are using a 16x16 grid */
            padding: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .imgCanvas {
            z-index: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
         }

        .canvas {
            cursor: crosshair;
            z-index: 10000;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;

        }

        .buttons {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1600px;
        }

        .saveButton {
            position: relative;
            top: 1600px;
            z-index: 20000;
        }

        .boxname {
            padding: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1600px;

        }

        .boxcolour {
            padding: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1600px;
        }

        .submitButton {
            padding: 6px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1600px;
        }

        .coordinates {
            display: block;
            padding:8px;
        }
    </style>

    <dom-module id="my-dialog-styles" theme-for="vaadin-dialog-overlay">
        <template>
            <style include="lumo-color lumo-typography">
                h3 {
                    margin-top: 0;
                }

                vaadin-form-layout {
                    max-width: 30em;
                }

                .buttons {
                    padding: var(--lumo-space-s) var(--lumo-space-l);
                    margin: calc(var(--lumo-space-l) * -1);
                    margin-top: var(--lumo-space-l);
                    border-top: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
                }

                .buttons > :last-child {
                    margin-left: auto;
                }

                .buttons > :nth-last-child(2) {
                    margin-right: var(--lumo-space-m);
                }

                .confirm-buttons {
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    padding: var(--lumo-space-xs) var(--lumo-space-m);
                    margin-top: var(--lumo-space-m);
                }

                .has-padding {
                    padding: 0 var(--lumo-space-l);
                    margin: 0 calc(var(--lumo-space-l) * -1);
                }

                .confirm-text {
                    max-width: 25em;
                    line-height: var(--lumo-line-height-s);
                }

                .confirm-text > * {
                    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
                }

                .confirm-text div:not(:first-child) {
                    color: var(--lumo-secondary-text-color);
                    font-size: var(--lumo-font-size-s);
                }
            </style>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
</custom-style>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose wrapping both canvases in a div or other element.

Then give that wrapper element `position: relative`, this means that absolutely positioned elements inside it with be relative to it, instead of relative to the page or some other parent element.

Absolutely positioned elements do not take up space, so only make the second canvas absolute, this way the first one will still take up space.

The structure should be something like this

`Wrapper - position relative`
    `Canvas 1 - normal positioning`
    `Canvas 2 - absolute position, left 0 top 0`
`Rest of elements outside the wrapper`